# Django Get First Letter of String

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I get the first letter of a string in a template with Django? I tried using the `truncatechars` filter, but it adds an ellipsis at the end.

```
{{ stringvariable | truncatechars:1 }}
```

I would like to go from "John" to "J".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use built-in [`slice` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{{ stringvariable|slice:"1" }}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> t = Template('{{ stringvariable|slice:"1" }}')
>>> c = Context({'stringvariable': 'John'})
>>> t.render(c)
u'J'
```